# Shell script with grep and sed to extract individuals from a pair after comparing the numerical values of a variable

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I want to compare a group of words (individuals) in pairs and extract the one with the lowest numeric variable. My files and scripts are made this way.

Relatedness_3rdDegree.txt (example):

```
Individual1 Individual2
Individual5 Individual23
Individual50 Individual65
```

filename.imiss

```
INDV    N_DATA  N_GENOTYPES_FILTERED    N_MISS  F_MISS
Individual1 375029  0   782 0.00208517
Individual2 375029  0   341 0.000909263
Individual3 375029  0   341 0.000909263
```

Main script:

```
numlines=$(wc -l Relatedness_3rdDegree.txt|awk '{print $1}')

for line in `seq 1 $numlines`
do
ind1=$(sed -n "${line}p" Relatedness_3rdDegree.txt|awk '{print $1}')
ind2=$(sed -n "${line}p" Relatedness_3rdDegree.txt|awk '{print $2}')
miss1=$(grep $ind1 filename.imiss|awk '{print $5}')
miss2=$(grep $ind2 filename.imiss|awk '{print $5}')
if echo "$miss1 > $miss2" | bc -l | grep -q 1
then
echo $ind1 >> miss.txt
else
echo $ind2 >> miss.txt
fi
echo "$line / $numlines"
done
```

This last script will echo a series of line like this :

```
1 / 208
2 / 208
3 / 208
```

and so on, until getting to this error:

```
91 / 208
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
92 / 208
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
93 / 208
```

If I go to my output (miss.txt), the printed individuals are not correct.
It should print the individuals, within the pairs contained in the file "Relatedness_3rdDegree.txt", that have the lowest value of F_MISS (column $5 of the "filename.imiss").

For instance, in the pair "Individual1 Individual2", it should compare their values of F_MISS and print only the individual with the lowest value, which in this example would be Individual 2.

I have manually checked the values and the printed individual, and it looks like it printed random individuals per each pair.

What is wrong in this script?

Comment: It's possible the error message is coming from not quoting the variables in the `grep` commands. I would also add `--` to protect against the values of those variables starting with dashes. Example: `miss1=$(grep -- "$ind1" filename.imiss|awk '{print $5}')`. Note that your script is very inefficient because it scans files four times for every line in the relatedness file. I would use an associative array to store the date from the imiss file and scan the relationship and look up the values in the array. I'll try to write an example or two using this technique and replace my previous answer.

Comment: `grep individual5 filename.imiss` can match a lot more like `individual50` and `individual51`

Comment: Can you show the output of `sed -n "92p" Relatedness_3rdDegree.txt|awk '{print $2}'`. Your error can be caused by an empty `miss1`. Try `echo " > " | bc -l`

Comment: Can an indiviual have a space in its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash version:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
declare -A imiss
while read -r ind nd ngf nm fm     # we'll ignore most of these
do 
    imiss[$ind]=$fm
done < filename.imiss

while read -r i1 i2
do
    if (( $(echo "${imiss[$i1]} > ${imiss[$i2]}" | bc -l) ))
    then 
        echo "$i1"
    else
        echo "$i2"
    fi
done < Relatedness_3rdDegree.txt
```

Run* it like:

```
bash-imiss
```

AWK version:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
NR == FNR {imiss[$1] = $5; next}

{
    if (imiss[$1] > imiss[$2]) {
        print $1
    } else {
        print $2
    }
}
```

Run* it like:

```
awk-imiss filename.imiss Relatedness_3rdDegree.txt
```

These two scripts do exactly the same thing in exactly the same way using associative arrays.

* This assumes that you have set the script file executable using `chmod` and that it's in your `PATH` and that the data files are in your current directory.

Comment: Which kind of additional information I could provide? I tried your command but I got this error: `join: Relatedness_3rdDegree.txt:14: is not sorted: Spanish_HG01524 IBS_HG01524
join: filename.imiss:53: is not sorted: MAK_MAK13 375029 0 6391 0.0170413`
I believe they need to be sorted in the same order, I will try

Comment: The command can't work because my two files have different lenghts. The input Relatedness_3rdDegree.txt as 208 lines, while the other has over a thousand. That's why in mi initial script, to address the issue I stated the number of lines

Comment: The answer has been edited. the `join` is removed. Both methods look nice. When `Relatedness_3rdDegree.txt` can have 6 fields (space in the name or a field to the right), the solution needs some changes.